# TypeError: hr.employee(26,) is not JSON serializable

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I tried to apply domain for many2one field. But I got the following Error:

```html
  @api.mutli
  def open_other_view(self):
      ......
      ......
      ......
      tree_id = self.env.ref('module_name.tree_xml_id').id
      return {
         'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
         'name': 'title',
         'views': [(tree_id, 'tree'), (False, 'form')],
         'domain' : [('employee_id','=',self.employee_id)],
         ....
         ....
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to obtain the employee id like:

```
'domain' : [('employee_id','=',self.employee_id.id)]
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: I tried it, it doesnt throw errors but it brings all the employees

Comment: @SOS-Mona this answer is correct and you should mark it as correct and if it shows all employees this means you are doing something wrong. please provide more code to see where the problem is

Comment: @SOS-Mona If it's returning all employees, that may mean that the `self.employee_id.id` is evaluating to `False`. If not, you should update your question with more details.